# Inserting image error, texts works fine

Tags: php, wordpress, multisite

I use Wordpress Multisite.

I am trying to insert an image to a page, but as soon as I click update it gives me an Error 406 or 404 on my page depending on Theme. If I only post texts the page displays properly just without a picture.

Works fine with only text. I have tried to insert with sql and it works too, but it doesn't work with wordpress editor.

Comment: works with relative path, broken when i write "http://" on src

Answer (score -1):

I fix it!
In my host, have enable "modsecurity", when enable, any url by other domain are blocked, disable modsecurity and be happy